# Recebo muitos erros no Android Studio ao querer compilar o meu projecto

Tags: java, android-studio

São muitos erros e eu nem percebo porquê. Por favor ajuda.[image: Os erros]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só um erro, e está na primeira linha:

```
unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

52.0 corresponde ao Java 8, e você está executando no Java 7.

Comment: Cara, isso ainda continua com os mesmos erros!

Comment: Eu é que falhei, apenas tinha instalado o Java 8 mas, não tinha configurado o Android Studio para executar com o Java 8, por isso ainda dava os mesmo erros! Mas, já está! Valeu...